# C++ Memory violation error when trying to use function with variable of arguments

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I want to create a function, that will log information to a file. This function needs to get some number of arguments and should iterate over them and print them to console. I have the following code:

```cpp
void log(int argnum ...)
{
    va_list arguments;
    std::string argval;
    va_start(arguments, argnum);

    for (int i = 0; i < argnum; i++) {
        argval = va_arg(arguments, std::string);
        std::cout << argval;
    }

    va_end(arguments);
}
```

And when I try to call the function like this:

```
log(10, "somebody", "once", "told", "me",
        "the", "world", "is", "gonna", "roll", "me");
```

Visual Studio opens "memcpy.asm" and I get Access violation error. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: is `"somebody"` an `int` ? most of the time a variadic function template is the better option

Comment: None of those are `std::string`s, they're `const char*`s.

Comment: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#-es34-dont-define-a-c-style-variadic-function

Comment: Why people are using this painful C macro stuff from the early 70s in todays c++ code? Why not simply `std::vector<std::string>>&`?

Comment: All the vararg functions are C functions. They don't understand C++ objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, your code is a bit messy. You declared `log` to take parameters of type `int`:

> ```
> void log(int argnum ...)
> ```

You then try to get them as `std::string`s:

> ```
> argval = va_arg(arguments, std::string);
> ```

And you try to call the function with parameters of type `int` and `const char[]`. Moreover, you seem to have a misconeption about how to deal with the number of arguments.

Most of the time, a variadic function template is the better option for vararg functions:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...T>
void log(const T& ... args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args) << '\n';
}
```